# how to add list option in excel (2010) without having options in different cells

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2010

I want to add options like `"WIP", "Assigned" , "Completed"` to a column and make it a drop down list. 
I found [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/) that it can be done using `"Data Validation"` by having options in different cells . Can I achieve the same without having the options in different cells?!

Can I just specify the option values!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data Validation in two ways:

1. use a list in some worksheet column
2. type the list directly into the Dialog

You probably want the second option.
In the source you can type in the options you need like Assigned,Completed,Wip

Comment: how should I type in ?! Just 
"assigned","WIP" etc!?

Comment: YES!!  first click on **Allow > List**  and then in **source** type the list in without double-quotes......not many people know about this.